# Same private keys, address started with 3 in electrum, but address started with 1 in electron cash

Tags: electrum, bitcoin-cash

I have a electrum wallet with 2fa. The addresses in this wallet all start with 3. When I export private keys and import them in electron cash to get Bitcoin cash, the addresses start with 1 instead. And the balance shows 0.

Why? What should I do to get my Bitcoin cash?

Comment: An adress starting with 3 is either segwit or Multisignature, and segwit isn't supported by BCH, hence why it would start with a 1 on their chain.

Comment: @RutgerV. BCH does support multisignature though (and P2SH in general), which is what electrum uses with 2FA I believe, so your comment is incorrect